# Neo4j color added automatically without adding

Tags: neo4j

I have added a color to particular node type and deleted the database. And if I load the database again, it is taking the same color for that node.

Do we need to delete any caches?

Answer (score 0):

try to clean the browser cache

Comment: Ok, and one more question, while loading data in local system it is fine, but when the same database trying to load in VM some of the nodes are not displaying names

Comment: create a new question as this is a new topic